# No known instance method for selector--delegate issue?

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I'm getting the above error, and I don't know why. The line where the error is flagged is:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{    
    [self.delegate addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];
}
```

I'm confused because there seems to be no problem with this method, immediately preceding:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
...          
    [self.delegate addViewControllerDidSave];
}
...       
}
```

My protocol is declared like this in the associated header file:

```
@protocol AddActivityViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) addViewControllerDidSave;

-(void) addViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete;

@end
```

and the methods are implemented like this in the delegate object:

```
-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete
{
    [activityToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}
```

Can someone please point out my mistake?

**Edit:**

There is indeed a naming problem (I was pasting in from a test app). However, I have corrected it, I believe, like so:

```
@protocol AddActivityViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) AddActivityViewControllerDidSave;

-(void) AddActivityViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete;

@end
```

And

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender

{
...
    [self.delegate AddActivityViewControllerDidSave];
...
}
```

And

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{    
    [self.delegate addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];
}
```

And

```
-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete
{
    [activityToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}
```

Still getting error.

Build fails even with breakpoint suggested by @Leo

Comment: @bneely Put your answer back. It was correct. Leo is mistaken.

Comment: This looks like an issue of `self.delegate` being type `id` without conforming to the relevant protocol.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: @LeoNatan `id` is a type. It's in **objc.h** on line 46 in the iOS 7.0.4 SDK.

Comment: @LeoNatan Please post an answer if you know of one. Thank you.

Comment: What do you you need to know. Happy to oblige!

Comment: Please see edit above, Leo.

Comment: @TimJones Wait, you can't compile or get a runtime exception? Could be this all was a misunderstanding

Comment: @Leo, I did say the build fails, and it won't run.

Comment: @rmaddy All this time I thought it was a runtime exception, which the answer was incorrect for. Compiler refusing to compile (with ARC) is a syntactic sugar issue.

Comment: @LeoNatan That may be true in the end but the whole point of using protocols, defining methods in them, and indicating that classes conform to them is to help the programmer write better code and for the compiler to find potential bugs at compile time. Yes it is all syntactic sugar but it's yummy sugar. It all avoids runtime crashes resulting in "unrecognized selector" errors. Better to find problems at compile-time than runtime.

Comment: @rmaddy Too much sugar and you have diabetes. :-)

Comment: @TimJones Breakpoints won't help with compiler issues. They are only useful when you app is actually running.

Comment: Please see comment below answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code:

- Your protocol defines method names without the word **Activity**, but your implementation defines method names with the word **Activity**, so those method names do not match. You can rely on completion or copy-paste to implement a protocol method and be sure the method signature matches.
- `self.delegate` may simply be type `id`, which does not conform to a specific protocol. The compiler has no way of knowing that `self.delegate` can respond to your protocol methods. Change that line to:

  `[(id<AddActivityViewControllerDelegate>)self.delegate addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];`

Comment: id absolutely is a type: **objc.h**: `typedef struct objc_object *id;`

Comment: @TimJones Did you try my suggested edit to your code in the second bullet point?

Comment: @bneely All this time I thought it was a runtime exception

Comment: Yes I believe my correction would have complied with your suggestion. It was just necessary to get everything in the protocol and methods to match, correct?

Comment: @TimJones I also made the suggestion to add `(id<AddActivityViewControllerDelegate>)` just before `self.delegate`. I believe this is the remaining issue in your code (from what I see in your question).

Comment: I just added that line, but still see the same error. Build fails, won't run.

Comment: @TimJones Slow down and take the time to proofread. Check the case of the method names in the protocol, how you call those methods, and how you implement those methods. Make sure all three match.

Comment: That was exactly it,@rmaddy! I can hardly believe it, but when I retraced my steps, The initial problem was what bneely saw, a disparity in the names between the protocol and the method. I corrected that by selecting and copying the "AddActivity" from the protocol declaration and pasting it to replace the "add" of my original method declarations. This fixed the spelling, but introduced a capitalization problem, which threw an identical exception. I apologize for taking up so much of your time! I think it proper to give bneely the green checkmark and up vote, but thanks to all!