# No known instance method for selector setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have developed my app in Xcode 7.3. When I open the project in Xcode 9.2, I got the error in AppDelegate:

> "No known instance method for selector 'setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate'"

My code is

```
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)statusBarHidden
{
    _statusBarHidden = statusBarHidden;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] tw_isRunningiOS7OrLater])
    {
        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237649/no-known-instance-method-for-selector-delegate-issue

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No known instance method for selector--delegate issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237649/no-known-instance-method-for-selector-delegate-issue)